# Get path lengths for every relationship neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So I have a graph that looks like this(starting from the rightmost side) with relationships that have a unique number attribute called Isnad. I want to write a query to get the length of every Isnad from the start node to the end node but I can't figure it out. I don't know how to traverse every path for every Isnad separately. Any help?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is the most elegant and solution, but I think it works. First, I'm getting all unique `Isnad` values of relationships outgoing from the rightmost side node using an identifier. Then I'm using a [variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) where all relationships have the same value for `Isnad` property. Then the `Isnad` value and the path length are returned.

```
match ({id:'unique-identifier-of-rightmost-side-node'})-[r]->()
with distinct r.Isnad as Isnad
match p = ()-[*{Isnad : Isnad}]->()
return Isnad, length(p) as Length
```

Comment: Thankyou! I had to modify it a little bit to only return the longest paths and also made it independent of the rightmost node id. But still your answer was really helpful.